# OpenGL lazy function(opengl function is delayed only at first frame)

Tags: opengl

At 'first' frame of my application, I don't know why 'glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT()' function is delayed. After first frame, this phenomenon doesn't occur.

That function is called in framebuffer bind method. Also, this phenomenon only occurs at summed-area table rendering 2nd pass using ping-pong technique. In this pass, render method exchanges src and dst textures. After calling glFramebufferTexture2D() and glDrawBuffers(), width() calls 'glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT()' function. I already replaced this code constant. But, next function was also delayed...... Strangely, this phenomenon is only occurred at 'first' frame of my application.

Here is my code in framebuffer bind method.

```
uint numDrawBuffers=0;
for( int k=0; k < MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS; k++ )
{
    gl::Texture* t=textureList[k]; GLint L=t?layerList[k]:0, M=t?mipLevelList[k]:0; GLuint tex=t?t->ID:0;
bool bnone = activeTargets[k]==NULL&&t==NULL;
    GLenum target = activeTargets[k] = (t?t->target:activeTargets[k]); if(t) numDrawBuffers++;

    if(bnone){ /* do nothing */ }
    else if(target==GL_TEXTURE_1D)          glFramebufferTexture1D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, drawBuffers[k], target, tex, M );
    else if(target==GL_TEXTURE_2D)          glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, drawBuffers[k], target, tex, M );
    else if(target==GL_TEXTURE_3D)          glFramebufferTextureLayer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, drawBuffers[k], tex, M, L );
    else if(target==GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY)    glFramebufferTextureLayer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, drawBuffers[k], tex, M, L );
    else if(target==GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY)    glFramebufferTextureLayer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, drawBuffers[k], tex, M, L );

    if(t==NULL) activeTargets[k] = NULL;
}

// if nothing bound, unbind depth buffer and return
if(numDrawBuffers==0){ glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,0); glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0); return; }
else glDrawBuffers( numDrawBuffers, drawBuffers );

GLint width=t0->width(mipLevel0), height=t0->height(mipLevel0);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'delayed'? Do you mean it takes very long to compute? Depending on the way how you load extension it could be, that the first opengl call has to initialize some function-pointer.

Comment: `glGet (...)` calls are round-trip. Of all the functions you mentioned, that's the only one that actually has to return the state of your GL object. The other functions you mentioned can all be queued up and return immediately... it's possible the texture state isn't fully initialized until you make that call the first time.

Comment: 'delayed' means that function returning is delayed. Commonly, each function takes micro seconds. However, in this case, it takes over 40ms.... It's very huge..